# Troubleshoot port forwarding. Could it be ISP blocking incoming connections?

Tags: networking, ip, port-forwarding, wide-area-network

Had a new Axis IP camera delivered yesterday. Plugged into Cisco E2400 Wireless Router but having problems.

Example topology:

- WAN IP:       82.10.10.10 (example)
- Cisco Router: 192.168.1.1
- Axis Camera:  192.168.1.10:80

Port forwarding rules set up on router

- External Port: 999
- Internal Port: 80
- Protocol: TCP & UDP
- Device IP: 192.168.1.10:80
- Enabled: True

Trying to connect from within the lan to 192.168.1.1:80 from within browser - Works properly.

Trying to connect from within the lan to 82:10:10:10:999 from within browser - Works properly.

Trying to connect from outside the LAN (e.g. via 3g or another isp) to 82:10:10:10:999 from within browser - Doesnt work.

I get the following errors from different machines / browsers:

- Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding (IOS)
- The server at 82.10.10.10 is taking too long to respond. (firefox)

This problem is not just for the Axis camera. I am also having similar problems connecting to my NAS drive.

After using a web based port scanning tool, it appears as though port 999 is closed. Not certain why when I have set up port forwarding within the router.

Any troubleshooting suggestions to help me determine whether the problem is with my Cisco settings / firewall or whether it could be my ISP blocking incoming connection requests?

Many thanks

Comment: Does your public IP actually start with `10.`? If so, it's unlikely you'll ever be able to get this to work.

Comment: 1. Do you mean Linksys E4200? 2. Is your "WAN IP" really a private address?

Comment: Amended. WAN Ip address is 82.XX.XX.XX

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that indeed your ISP is blocking the port 999. Some ISP's block all ports under 1024. Try forwarding a higher port on your router (f.e. 9999) to the ip camera and see if that works.

Answer (score -3):

Something like that happened to me with my web server at home. Using traceroute I have found out that my ISP is blocking ports